# Set listener to Android Service from Fragment

Tags: android, service, android-fragments

I have the below methods in my service that allow me to listen to certain actions performed on a service

```
public interface PlayerServiceListener {
    public void onTrackChange(HashMap<String, String> newtrack);
    public void onTrackStop();
    public void onTrackPause();
    public void onTrackPlay();
}
public void setListener(PlayerServiceListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Then from my Fragment  that implements PlayerServiceListener  I have the below ServiceConnection

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            loader.dismiss();

            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();

            mService.setListener(getActivity()); //The method setListener(playerService.PlayerServiceListener) 
            //in the type playerService is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentActivity)

            previous.setEnabled(true);
            play.setEnabled(true);
            next.setEnabled(true);

            if (mService.status == BNMplayerService.TRACK_STOP)
                mService.nextTrack();
            else { 
                if (mService.status == BNMplayerService.TRACK_PAUSED) {
                    play.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));

                } 
                if (mService.status == BNMplayerService.TRACK_PLAYING) {
                    play.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause));
                }

                onTrackChange(mService.getInfo());
            }
        }

        // Called when the connection with the service disconnects unexpectedly
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
             mService = null;
        }
    };
```

I want to set a listener to this service using the line

```
mService.setListener(getActivity());
```

But I get an error  (The method setListener(playerService.PlayerServiceListener) 
in the type playerService is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentActivity))

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you declare your local `mService`:

```
private MyPlayerServiceWithMyCustomMethod mService;
```

In your ServiceConnection cast your local variable:

```
LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
mService = (MyPlayerServiceWithMyCustomMethod)binder.getService();
mService.setListener(MyFragmentThatImplementsMyInterface.this);
```

Comment: Worked. Accepted as answer